# Apple watch gets very hot if charging from PC

Tags: charging, apple-watch

I have a Series 2 (Nike) Apple Watch.  Normally I've had it connected to my 2018 MacBook for charging, but I wanted to free up one of the USB-C ports (they are all in use), so decided to plug the watch into a USB port on my Windows desktop instead, since it doesn't need to "talk" to the Mac anyway.

I've noticed 2 things when doing this:

1. It seems to charge *much* more slowly than when connected to the Mac
2. It gets *very* warm, much warmer than when charging from the Mac.  Not "hot" or anything, like I couldn't wear it... but very noticeably warm.

Why would this happen?  Are there any best practices around charging an Apple Watch from sources other than a Mac?

Comment: A downvote?  Seriously?  People.  /smh.

Comment: Is your PC's usb port USB 2 or 3? Is the USB port hooked up via an extender?

Comment: USB 3 I believe (blue port).  No extender.

Comment: does it get warm if you put it back on the mac for one night? what about a different port on the computer. Finally, you can also try using a standard USB A charging brick

Comment: If I charge it from the Mac, it gets just slightly warm, like it always has.  But hugely different from charging on the PC where it is borderline HOT.  It also charges *much* faster on the Mac.  Different port seemed to charge even more slowly but that's subjective, I didn't time it or try to measure.  I haven't used a USB brick yet, will see what that does, though it's not a long term solution.

Comment: Huh, that’s weird. Does your PC have a lot of other usb devices attached  (chargers, cameras, etc.)? Does this heat & slowness occur when using the pc to charge your phone? In the meantime, you should stop charging the watch on the pc since heat & slowness can signal something wrong and even degrade your battery faster. Also, you may want to simply try rebooting your watch: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204510, though it probably won’t help.

Comment: It has a few devices connected but not many, and all low power.  I have never ever charged my phone on it, only on the Mac so I have no idea how that would go.  I did stop charging on the PC as soon as I noticed this, which was the same day so I'm confident no harm was done in the short span of time.  But it was charging for hours and only got from like 12% charge, to 50% charge, so something was definitely not right.  I really don't get it but for now, am back to charging on the mac.

Comment: It may be a one-off issue and some clash between the charger and your pc. You may have to stick to using your mac, or you could get a usb 3 extender (for the power) and connect it to a wall outlet far away.